# What's the convention for using an asterisk at the end of a function name in Clojure and other Lisp dialects?

Tags: clojure, coding-style, naming-conventions

Note that I'm not talking about ear muffs in symbol names, an issue that is discussed at [Conventions, Style, and Usage for Clojure Constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579063/conventions-style-and-usage-for-clojure-constants) and [How is the `*var-name*` naming-convention used in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986961/how-is-the-var-name-naming-convention-used-in-clojure).  I'm talking strictly about instances where there is some function named foo that then calls a function foo*.

Comment: You mean like in statements like `(let ((x 5) (y 10)))` vs `(let* ((x 5) (y 10)))`?

Comment: Assuming the answer to my comment is yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp

Comment: @Jimmy: Thanks for the link.  Is parallel vs. non-parallel binding the only difference between any foo/foo* functions?  Or are there other differences that could distinguish the two?  I'm not sure if this distinction applies to Clojure either...in Clojure, let uses sequential binding.

Answer (score 52):

In Clojure it basically means "foo* is like foo, but somehow different, and you probably want foo". In other words, it means that the author of that code couldn't come up with a better name for the second function, so they just slapped a star on it.

Comment: In particular, "foo*" is often a function that accomplishes some metaprogramming task in a syntactically annoying way, and "foo" is a macro providing a more syntactically pleasing abstraction on top of it. This minimizes the amount of logic in the macro and pushes as much as possible into the function, where it is usually easier to understand and debug, while still maintaining a minimal macro on top for its syntax transformation capabilities.

Answer (score 16):

Mathematicians and Haskellers can use their apostrophes to indicate similar objects (values or functions). Similar but not quite the same. Objects that relate to each other. For instance, function `foo` could be a calculation in one manner, and `foo'` would do the same result but with a different approach. Perhaps it is unimaginative naming but it has roots in mathematics.

Lisps generally (without any terminal reason) have discarded apostrophes in symbol names, and `*` kind of resembles an apostrophe. Clojure 1.3 will finally fix that by allowing apostrophes in names!

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question correctly, I've seen instances where `foo*` was used to show that the function is equivalent to another in theory, but uses different semantics. Take for instance the [lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina) library, which defines things like `map*`, `filter*`, `take*` for its core type, channels. Channels are similar enough to seqs that the names of these functions make sense, but they are not compatible enough that they should be "equal" per se.

Another use case I've seen for `foo*` style is for functions which call out to a helper function with an extra parameter. The `fact` function, for instance, might delegate to `fact*` which accepts another parameter, the accumulator, if written recursively. You don't necessarily want to expose in `fact` that there's an extra argument, because calling `(fact 5 100)` isn't going to compute for you the factorial of 5--exposing that extra parameter is an error.

I've also seen the same style for macros. The macro `foo` expands into a function call to `foo*`.

Comment: from http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Library+Coding+Standards:

`Don't use a macro when a function can do the job. If a macro is important for ease-of-use, expose the function version as well. 

Open question: should there be a naming convention here? A lot of places use "foo" and "foo*".`

Answer (score 1):

a normal let binding `(let ((...)))` create separate variables in parallel

a let star binding `(let* ((...)))` creates variables sequentially so that can be computed from eachother like so

```
(let* ((x 10) (y (+ x 5)))
```

I could be slightly off base but see [LET versus LET* in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554949/let-versus-let-in-common-lisp) for more detail

EDIT: I'm not sure about how this reflects in Clojure, I've only started reading Programming Clojure so I don't know yet

Comment: it's opposite in Clojure, actually.